# I keep getting, "NoMethodError (undefined method `moments' for nil:NilClass):"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I'm just start to learn ruby and I'm writing a simple API, but I've got an error NoMethodError (undefined method `moments' for nil:NilClass):  app/controllers/api/v1/moments_controller.rb:8:in`index' Here is a code:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   resources :posts 
   devise_for :users
   namespace :api do
      namespace :v1 do
        devise_scope :user do
         post 'registrations' => 'registrations#create', :as => 'register'
         post 'sessions' => 'sessions#create', :as => 'login'
         delete 'sessions' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => 'logout'
       end
      get 'moments' => 'moments#index', :as => 'moments'
      post 'moments' => 'moments#create'
   end
  end
  devise_scope :user do  
    get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'     
  end
end`
```

here code : moments_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::MomentsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token,
                     :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @moments = current_user.moments
  end

  def create

    @moment = current_user.moments.build(params[:moment])

    if @moment.save
       @moment
    else
      render :status => :unprocessable_entity,
             :json => { :success => false,
                        :info => @moment.errors,
                        :data => {} }
    end
  end

  #private
   # def moment_params
   #   params.require(:moment).permit(:title, :completed)
   # end

end
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Where in your code do you assign a value to `current_user`?

Comment: The reason you get that error is that `current_user` is `nil`.

Comment: Is Devise set up and working properly? `before_filter :authenticate_user!` should ensure `current_user` is defined, but it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: i m using https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication now i have message error : {"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."

Comment: Sounds right. So you just need to make sure you're signed in before you visit that API endpoint.

Comment: soo. would you help me to resolve problem , how to get current_user ?